# Loading Thymeleaf templates from external source(outside of JAR file) in non Spring Boot application

Tags: java, thymeleaf

While calling **getTemplate()** method it's throwing this error -
**"Error resolving template [betreff_product_request], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers"**.
Is it because of the wrong path I've mentioned in **templateResolver.setPrefix("D:\\templates\\");?**.
How can I solve this?

```
public class MailerTemplateEngine {
    private final TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public MailerTemplateEngine() {

        this.templateEngine = new org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine();
        FileTemplateResolver  templateResolver = new FileTemplateResolver ();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("D:\\templates\\");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".txt");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
        templateResolver.setOrder(templateEngine.getTemplateResolvers().size());
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);
        this.templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    }

    public String getTemplate(String templateName, HashMap<String,String> parameters) {
        Context ctx = new Context();

        if (parameters != null) {
            parameters.forEach((k, v) -> {
                ctx.setVariable(k, v);
            });
        }

        return this.templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx).trim();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you running this inside a (non-Spring) web app? If so, which one? Otherwise how are you running this (e.g. a standalone Java JAR, etc.)?

Comment: For what it's worth, your code runs fine in my environment (standalone JAR, no web server). I can open a text template and process it with Thymeleaf directives. That suggests the problem lies elsewhere. File access permissions? File name mismatch?

Comment: The Thymleaf part is implemented inside a Maven application and from another Spring Boot application, I'm getting the Maven application features.

Comment: Thanks and the problem was, my Maven application was running on a server and I was trying to get the Thymleaf template folder which was in my local drive. Now I put the template folder in the server and it's running fine.